# migrate metadata from a empty org to an old org

Tags: metadata, migration-tool, configuration, developer-org

I'm working on an empty developer org and we would like to migrate all of this org to another org but actually override the previous metadata? Is that possible?

More on detail, we were bought by another company that didn't use Salesforce before. We have been using salesforce for 5 years but due to this transition we will use a new ERP as well. So, We want to make a fresh new start and take advantage of lightning experience but we don't want to keep anything from the old company. We have a backup of everything just in case but definitely we want to start from scratch on our production org.

We don't need to buy new licences for a new org as we are getting a special price and this means that will lose this (We already spoke with the account manager).

So, can i override a prod org's metadata from another one?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can always purge the metadata using ANT scripts and Purge=true flag.

this will help in wipe the slate clean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However according to the documentation in prod you can't purge.
"If true, the deleted components in the destructiveChanges.xml manifest file aren't stored in the Recycle Bin. Instead, they become immediately eligible for deletion.This option only works in Developer Edition or sandbox orgs; it doesn't work in production orgs."